# how to sum the last 12 months of data in a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two joined tables, customers and orders, both linked by CustomerPK.

On the customer tale i am trying to sum the total spend of each customer (taking sum from join to orders table) and then also caluclate the last 12 months spend for that customer, it is this last line that isnt working, here is my code:

```
SELECT
customers.CustomerPk,
customers.CustomerCode,
customers.CustomerName,
customers.AddressLine1,
customers.AddressLine2,
customers.AddressLine3,
customers.AddressLine4,
customers.AddressLine5,
customers.Town,
customers.County,
customers.PostCode,
customers.Country,
SUM(orders.OrderValue) AS `Total Spend`,
SUM(orders.OrderValue) WHERE orders.OrderDate >= curdate() - interval 1 year as `Last 12 Month Spend`
FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON customers.CustomerPk = orders.CustomerFk
GROUP BY customers.CustomerPk, customers.CustomerCode, customers.CustomerName, customers.AddressLine1, customers.AddressLine2, customers.AddressLine3, customers.AddressLine4, customers.AddressLine5, customers.Town, customers.County, customers.PostCode, customers.Country
```

The table was working until i added the following line:
    SUM(orders.OrderValue) WHERE orders.OrderDate >= curdate() - interval 1 year as `Last 12 Month Spend`

I need this WHERE statement to apply only to this line and not to the overall table as it will remove results.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a `WHERE` clause to a column. But if you want to sum only values for which a condition is met you can use a `CASE` expression in the `sum()`. If your condition is met, return the value, that should be added to the sum. Otherwise return zero -- the sum won't change if you add zero.

```
...
sum(CASE
      WHEN orders.orderdate >= curdate() - interval 1 year THEN
        orders.ordervalue       
      ELSE
        0
    END) `Last 12 Month Spend`
...
```